# How to use react component (@material-ui/core) in React native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, material-ui

I would like to ask is there any way I can use react component (@material-ui/core) in React Native?

When I use @material-ui/core components in React Native project, the App keep crashed because it cannot find the elements like div, p and span.

Thank you

in index.js

```
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import Demo from './Demo';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => Demo);
```

in Demo.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {View} from 'react-native';
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';

export default function Demo() {
  return (
    <View>
      <Card>
      </Card>
    </View>
  );
}
```

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmw00.png)

Comment: Cans you add the code on how you import it and use

Comment: updated the question, thanks

Answer (score 1):

React native uses *react-native-material-ui* whereas ReactJs uses *@material-ui/core*

```
npm i react-native-material-ui
```

```
import React from 'react';
import {View} from 'react-native';
import { Card } from 'react-native-material-ui';

export default function Demo() {
  return (
    <View>
      <Card>
      </Card>
    </View>
  );
}
```

[react-native-material-ui Docs](https://github.com/xotahal/react-native-material-ui)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but may I ask if react-native-material-ui and @material-ui are two separate project, or they have some kind of relationship?

Comment: They are similar but both reactjs and react-native have different frameworks. The @material-ui packages are built for webapps whereas react-native-material-ui is built for react-native.

Comment: Hope this helps. I've added the docs of react-native-material-ui in the answer

Comment: @joca does this provide an answer to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Material UI is meant for ReactJS(web apps), so it won't work in the React Native framework.